# how to convert encoded pcap file to decode text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have encoded .pcap file I like to decode the .pcap file with only speech information(payload)

I am using python 3.7

```
from pcapfile import savefile
testcap=open("filename.pcap",'rb')
capfile=savefile.load_savefile(testcap,layers=1,verbose=True)
# capfile1=savefile.load_savefile(testcap,)
# print(capfile.packets[0].packet.payload)

f=open("filename.txt","w+")
# data=capfile.packets[0].packet.payload
data=capfile.packets[0].packet.payload
# f.write(b(data).decode("utf-8"))
f.write(data.decode("utf-8"))
f.close()
```

I have to decode the .pcap file and save the .pcap file in a text document which should only have binary numbers and only payload information

Comment: Why have you tagged this C# and Java if you're using Python? You also don't seem to be using both Python 3.x and Python 2.7 at once right now.

Comment: I need to decode the .pcap  in any programming language. I tried python 3.X  to extract the file using this method.